# Futur ou conditionnel avec "jamais"

Tags: temps-grammatical

Pensez-vous qu'il faut écrire:

"Je ne **saurais** jamais vraiment ce qui s'est passé au cours de mes derniers jours dans la jungle."

Ou bien:

"Je ne **saurai** jamais vraiment ce qui s'est passé au cours de mes derniers jours dans la jungle."

Mon opinion est que "jamais" rend la tournure inconditionnelle ?

Edit: je ne sais pas si cela va clarifier le contexte, mais voici le paragraphe entier.

> Comme je l'avais promis à mon ami Agustin, je ne pris que deux idoles.
> Le chemin du retour fut moins ardu que je le redoutais. Était ce parce
> que la forêt me jugeait digne de repartir? Ou simplement parce que mon
> corps s'était finalement habitué à toutes ces privations ? Je ne
> saurais jamais vraiment ce qui s'est passé au cours de mes derniers
> jours dans la jungle. Je me souviens confusément d'avoir erré,
> halluciné, jusqu'à finalement me retrouver un matin dans le village
> d'où j'étais parti...

En complément, il me semble que si on remplace "je" par "il", le conditionnel sonne très mal. Mais j'aimerais avoir en réponse quelque chose de plus certain que ça.

Comment: Tout dépend du contexte ; donc il faudrait que vous ajoutiez les phrases qui rendent ce contexte clair.

Comment: Le choix du mode dépend du degré d'incertitude que vous ou l'auteur du texte voulez exprimer. Voici aussi un [lien](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/explication/).  Enfin... peut-être qu'avec _jamais_ le futur convient mieux. Mais attendons des avis de francophones.

Answer (score 4):

Bonjour,

Je suis d’accord avec votre conclusion finale. Le conditionnel est utilisé pour donner une information incertaine, non confirmée.
Comme il y a ‘jamais’, cela confirme l’information donnée: c’est sûr, certain que ‘je ne saurai pas ce qu’il s’est passé’.

Comment: Merci, donc sans "s" dans votre texte ?

Comment: @lemon Tout à fait.

Comment: @Sean213 Pourquoi y a-t-il un *S* à saurais dans la réponse alors ?

Comment: @jlliagre Faute de frappe, merci d’avoir remarqué.